# Where to find hot and cold operator for mable testing with rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to make unit test with rxjs. I found this documentation on rxjs github.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/writing-marble-tests.md

However, I have not succeded in finding `hot` and `cold` operators. Where can  find it ? If someone have an example I would be glad.

Comment: `hot` and `cold` are methods that return Observables, not operators.

Answer (score 0):

What framework are you using for your tests? If you use jasmine there is a npm package called `jasmine-marbles`, which is probably what you are searching for. There is also another package called `rxjs-marbles`, which provides utilities for marble testing. 
You can see an example for `jasmine-marbles` here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/testing.md 
And one for `rxjs-marbles` here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-marbles

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of asking the question, the documentation [was scarce](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/55296c960592dbe73f4042739d143b6e98dc0971/doc/writing-marble-tests.md). But it was updated later on with the addition of writing tests using TestScheduler and it's new `run()` method.

So, based on the new [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/testing/marble-testing.md), it is recommended to use `TestScheduler.run(callback)` method for marble testing. E.g.

```js
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';

const testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
  // asserting the two objects are equal
  // e.g. using chai.
  expect(actual).deep.equal(expected);
});

// This test will actually run *synchronously*
it('generate the stream correctly', () => {
  testScheduler.run(helpers => {
    const { cold, expectObservable, expectSubscriptions } = helpers;
    const e1 =  cold('-a--b--c---|');
    const subs =     '^----------!';
    const expected = '-a-----c---|';

    expectObservable(e1.pipe(throttleTime(3, testScheduler))).toBe(expected);
    expectSubscriptions(e1.subscriptions).toBe(subs);
  });
});
```

From this example, when you call `run` method, you should pass the `callback` function with `helpers` object as a receiving parameter. The `helpers` object contains all the stuff you need (`hot` and `cold` operators as well):

```js
testScheduler.run(helpers => {
  const { cold, hot, expectObservable, expectSubscriptions, flush } = helpers;
  // use them
});
```

For more info, please read the [official docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/testing/marble-testing.md).